# Batch file not giving correct results

Tags: batch-file, tree, cmd

I wm making a **.bat** file which will make the graphical representation of directories in different drives.But when i run it it does not give the correct result 
Here is my bat file code

```
@echo off
D:
tree /f /a > D:\d_drive.txt
tree /f /a > E:\d_drive.txt
tree /f /a > F:\d_drive.txt
tree /f /a > G:\d_drive.txt
tree /f /a > H:\d_drive.txt
E:
tree /f /a > D:\e_drive.txt
tree /f /a > E:\e_drive.txt
tree /f /a > F:\e_drive.txt
tree /f /a > G:\e_drive.txt
tree /f /a > H:\e_drive.txt
F:
tree /f /a > D:\f_drive.txt
tree /f /a > E:\f_drive.txt
tree /f /a > F:\f_drive.txt
tree /f /a > G:\f_drive.txt
tree /f /a > H:\f_drive.txt
G:
tree /f /a > D:\f_drive.txt
tree /f /a > E:\f_drive.txt
tree /f /a > F:\f_drive.txt
tree /f /a > G:\f_drive.txt
tree /f /a > H:\f_drive.txt
H:
tree /f /a > D:\g_drive.txt
tree /f /a > E:\g_drive.txt
tree /f /a > F:\g_drive.txt
tree /f /a > G:\g_drive.txt
tree /f /a > H:\g_drive.txt
```

When i run this file i get all the text files but having something like below in them

Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 00000200 2067:FF00
D:.
    New Text Document.bat

No subfolders exist

Comment: try `cd /d D:\` instead of just `D:`. If you just change the drive, you may not be in the root directory of that drive.

Comment: @Stephan Yes actually it is staying in ithe directory of the bat file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it like this

```
D:
cd/
tree /f /a > D:\d_drive.txt
```

if you are in `E:/test/test` and then you do `C:` and again you do `E:` you will be in `E:/test/test` not in `E:` . `cd/` will put you at root level

Answer (score 1):

`tree` needs a lot of time, so try to do it just once, then copy the result to the different locations.
Also you can tell `tree` where to start:

```
tree D:\ /f /a >D:\d_drive.txt
copy /y d:\d_drive.txt e:\
copy /y d:\d_drive.txt f:\
copy /y d:\d_drive.txt g:\
copy /y d:\d_drive.txt h:\
```

A more elegant way to do it:

```
for %%i in (d e f g h) do tree %%i:\ /f /a >%%i_drive.txt
for %%i in (d e f g h) do copy /y ?_drive.txt >%%i:\
```

(first step: create all trees; second step, distribute them)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off

set drives=d e f g h
for %%a in (%drives%) do (
   %%a:
   cd \
   tree /f /a > %%a_drive.txt
   for %%b in (%drives%) do (
      if %%a neq %%b copy %%a_drive.txt %%b:\
   )
)
```